# Increment next month with dayOfTheMonth SQL sybase

Tags: sql, database, date, stored-procedures, sybase

For this problem, I have two inputs:
@currentDate
@dayOfTheMonth

I wish to find/increment for every month for a year or more for example.

For instance, if I have 
@currenDate = 2012-06-14 (yyyy-mm-dd)
@dayOfTheMonth = 15 (between 1 and 29-30-31, depending on month)

first loop
@currentDate = 2012-06-15

second loop
@currentDate - 2012-07-15

third loop
@currentDate = 2012-08-15

etc.

Or let's take this to another level... for daily, weekly, biweekly, monthly, quaterly, semiannualy and annualy.

```
            WHEN @period = 'D' THEN 
            DATEADD(dd,(CASE DATEPART(cdw, @currentDate) WHEN @resetDay THEN 7 ELSE @resetDay - DATEPART(cdw,@currentDate) END),@currentDate) 
            WHEN @period = 'W' THEN 
            DATEADD(dd,(CASE DATEPART(cdw, @currentDate) WHEN @resetDay THEN 7 ELSE @resetDay - DATEPART(cdw,@currentDate) END),@currentDate) 
            WHEN @period = 'B' THEN 
            DATEADD(dd,(CASE DATEPART(cdw, @currentDate) WHEN @resetDay THEN 14 ELSE @resetDay - DATEPART(cdw,@currentDate) END),@currentDate) 
            WHEN @period = 'M' THEN 
            CASE @resetDay - DATEPART(dd, @currentDate) WHEN 0 THEN DATEADD(mm, 1, @currentDate) ELSE DATEADD(dd, @resetDay - DATEPART(dd, @currentDate), @currentDate) END     
            WHEN @period = 'Q' THEN 
            CASE @resetDay - DATEPART(dd, @currentDate) WHEN 0 THEN DATEADD(mm, 4, @currentDate) ELSE DATEADD(dd, @resetDay - DATEPART(dd, @currentDate), @currentDate) END 
            WHEN @period = 'S' THEN 
            CASE @resetDay - DATEPART(dd, @currentDate) WHEN 0 THEN DATEADD(mm, 6, @currentDate) ELSE DATEADD(dd, @resetDay - DATEPART(dd, @currentDate), @currentDate) END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Declare @currentDate datetime Set @currentDate = getdate()
Declare @dayOfTheMonth int Set @dayOfTheMonth = 15

Select 1,DateAdd(month,1, DateAdd(day, @dayOfTheMonth - DatePart(day, @currentDate),@currentDate))
union all 
Select 2,DateAdd(month,2, DateAdd(day, @dayOfTheMonth - DatePart(day, @currentDate),@currentDate))
union all
Select 3,DateAdd(month,3, DateAdd(day, @dayOfTheMonth - DatePart(day, @currentDate),@currentDate))
union all 
Select 4,DateAdd(month,4, DateAdd(day, @dayOfTheMonth - DatePart(day, @currentDate),@currentDate))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Period conditions
      T = Bullet 
      D = Daily 
      W = Weekly 
      B = Bi-Weekly 
      M = Monthly 
      Q = Quarterly 
      S = SemiAnnually 
      Y = Annual 
 */ 

 SELECT @currentDate = CASE 
        WHEN @period = 'T' THEN 
          @endDate 
        WHEN @period = 'D' THEN 
                DATEADD(dd,1,@currentDate) 
        WHEN @period = 'W' THEN 
                DATEADD(dd,( 
      CASE 
      WHEN @resetDay - DATEPART(cdw,@currentDate) <= 0 THEN @resetDay - DATEPART(cdw,@currentDate)+7 
      ELSE 
      @resetDay - DATEPART(cdw,@currentDate) 
      END),@currentDate) 
        WHEN @period = 'B' THEN 
                DATEADD(dd,( 
      CASE 
      WHEN @resetDay - DATEPART(cdw,@currentDate) <= 0 THEN @resetDay - DATEPART(cdw,@currentDate)+14 
      ELSE 
      @resetDay - DATEPART(cdw,@currentDate) 
      END),@currentDate) 
  WHEN @period = 'M' THEN 
      CASE 
      WHEN @resetDay - DATEPART(dd,@currentDate) <= 0 THEN DATEADD(mm, 1, DATEADD(dd, @resetDay - DATEPART(dd, @currentDate),@currentDate)) 
      ELSE 
      DATEADD(dd, @resetDay - DATEPART(dd, @currentDate), @currentDate) 
      END                 
        WHEN @period = 'Q' THEN 
                CASE 
      WHEN @resetDay - DATEPART(dd,@currentDate) <= 0 THEN DATEADD(mm, 3, DATEADD(dd, @resetDay - DATEPART(dd, @currentDate),@currentDate)) 
      ELSE 
      DATEADD(dd, @resetDay - DATEPART(dd, @currentDate), @currentDate) 
      END                       
        WHEN @period = 'S' THEN 
            CASE 
      WHEN @resetDay - DATEPART(dd,@currentDate) <= 0 THEN DATEADD(mm, 6, DATEADD(dd, @resetDay - DATEPART(dd, @currentDate),@currentDate)) 
      ELSE 
      DATEADD(dd, @resetDay - DATEPART(dd, @currentDate), @currentDate) 
      END                 
        WHEN @period = 'Y' THEN 
          @endDate 
    END
```